# Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 2.3 — Are all closed sets (w.r.t. addition and scalar multiplication) convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am asking this question because in Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) there is an exercise (2.3) about midpoint convexity which says that

> [...] As a simple case, prove that if $C$ is closed and midpoint convex, then $C$ is convex.

Now I find the the mid point convexity condition redundant because if set is closed w.r.t addition and multiplication, it will be convex. Am I right or there is a problem with my reasoning. Or is there any counterexample to this with existence of non-convex closed set? My intution is as follows.

Let $a,b \in  \mathbb{R} $ and $v_1,v_2 \in S$. Now for closed set we will have
$av_1+bv_2 \in S $. For convexity $a+b = 1$ and $a,b \geq 0$. Since $av_1+bv_2 \in S $ holds for all $\mathbb{R}$ it will hold for restricted condition for convexity as well. So dose this imply that every closed set is also a convex set?

Comment: The question is "why is it obvious". It may be redundant and the proof may be easy, but it still needs to be done in terms of the definition of convexity.

Comment: I believe that "closed" in this context is referring to the topological property (roughly speaking, it contains all its limit points), rather than being closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: @GregMartin You seems right. Thanks. But is it true that all closed sets (w.r.t) addition and multiplication are convex?

Comment: If $S$ is closed under both operations and $s,t\in S$, then directly from those assumptions $\lambda s+(1-\lambda) t\in S$, even without the restriction $\lambda\in[0,1]$. In fact, a (nonempty) set that is closed under addition and scalar multiplication is a vector subspace, and subspaces are certainly convex.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)